# Deleting array (related with textchange event)

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am using TextChanged event and when I am pressing keyboard, numbers are going into array... the question is:
When I am deleting any numbers I want to delete in the array list too 
but cause of textchange event I already added an element I just want to delete the element and add another element

How do I do this?

```
    long i;
    long[] array1 = new long[11];
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            array1[i] = long.Parse(textBox1.Text) % 10;
            //MessageBox.Show(array1[i].ToString());
        }
        catch
        {
            if (i > 10)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("it can be bigger than 11");
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove an element from the list. Use `List<T>` collection.

```
List<long> list=new List<long>();
list.Add(100);
list.Add(200);
//To remove a number
list.Remove(100);
```

EDIT:

You may separate each digit of input text (Add textBox1 and listBox1 control):

```
   int[] ar;
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
      ar = textBox1.Text.Select(p => p - 48).ToArray();
      listBox1.DataSource = ar;
     }
```

Comment: @y.baris - Its an LINQ expression (extension method with lambda expression). Please read MSDN page on LINQ and lambda expression.

Comment: @y.baris - Not necessary. ListBox is for displaying data while typing text.

Comment: Can I ask a other question to you.İt's about knight movement on chess table.I bored to think about it.